# Get total amount of free GPU memory and available using pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch, gpu, google-colaboratory

I'm using google colab free Gpu's for experimentation and wanted to know how much GPU Memory available to play around, torch.cuda.memory_allocated() returns the current GPU memory occupied, but how do we determine total available memory using PyTorch.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

In the recent version of PyTorch you can also use torch.cuda.mem_get_info:

https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.cuda.mem_get_info.html#torch.cuda.mem_get_info

```
torch.cuda.mem_get_info()
```

It returns a tuple where the first element is the free memory usage and the second is the total available memory.

Comment: This is better than the accepted answer (using `total_memory` + reserved/allocated) as it provides correct numbers when other processes/users share the GPU and take up memory.

Comment: In older versions of pytorch, this is buggy, it ignores the device parameter and always returns current device info. The workaround is to use this with a context manager:
`with torch.cuda.device(device):`
         `info = torch.cuda.mem_get_info()`

see:
[https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/76224](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/76224)

Comment: Example usage please

Comment: @NathanB Added example usage.

Answer (score 114):

PyTorch can provide you total, reserved and allocated info:

```
t = torch.cuda.get_device_properties(0).total_memory
r = torch.cuda.memory_reserved(0)
a = torch.cuda.memory_allocated(0)
f = r-a  # free inside reserved
```

Python bindings to NVIDIA can bring you the info for the whole GPU (0 in this case means first GPU device):

```
from pynvml import *
nvmlInit()
h = nvmlDeviceGetHandleByIndex(0)
info = nvmlDeviceGetMemoryInfo(h)
print(f'total    : {info.total}')
print(f'free     : {info.free}')
print(f'used     : {info.used}')
```

<sub>pip install pynvml</sub>

You may check the `nvidia-smi` to get memory info.
You may use `nvtop` but this tool needs to be installed from source (at the moment of writing this).
Another tool where you can check memory is gpustat (`pip3 install gpustat`).

If you would like to use C++ cuda:

```
include <iostream>
#include "cuda.h"
#include "cuda_runtime_api.h"
  
using namespace std;
  
int main( void ) {
    int num_gpus;
    size_t free, total;
    cudaGetDeviceCount( &num_gpus );
    for ( int gpu_id = 0; gpu_id < num_gpus; gpu_id++ ) {
        cudaSetDevice( gpu_id );
        int id;
        cudaGetDevice( &id );
        cudaMemGetInfo( &free, &total );
        cout << "GPU " << id << " memory: free=" << free << ", total=" << total << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `torch.cuda.memory_cached` has been renamed to `torch.cuda.memory_reserved`

Comment: Updated @Kallzvx. If something looks wring let me know.

Comment: Note: total_memory + reserved/allocated does not work well when memory is allocated by other users/processes.

Comment: use `import pynvml` instead of `from pynvml import *`, else this may cause conflict with other code. For example, modeling_roberta.py throws `TypeError: '_ctypes.UnionType' object is not subscriptable`.

`pynvml.nvmlInit()`,
`h = pynvml.nvmlDeviceGetHandleByIndex(0)`,
`info = pynvml.nvmlDeviceGetMemoryInfo(h)`

Answer (score 4):

This is useful for me!

```py
def get_memory_free_MiB(gpu_index):
    pynvml.nvmlInit()
    handle = pynvml.nvmlDeviceGetHandleByIndex(int(gpu_index))
    mem_info = pynvml.nvmlDeviceGetMemoryInfo(handle)
    return mem_info.free // 1024 ** 2
```

Answer (score 1):

I use this code:

```
def get_ram():
    mem = psutil.virtual_memory()
    free = mem.available / 1024 ** 3
    total = mem.total / 1024 ** 3
    total_cubes = 24
    free_cubes = int(total_cubes * free / total)
    return f'RAM: {total - free:.2f}/{total:.2f}GB\t RAM:[' + (total_cubes - free_cubes) * '▮' + free_cubes * '▯' + ']'


def get_vram():
    free = torch.cuda.mem_get_info()[0] / 1024 ** 3
    total = torch.cuda.mem_get_info()[1] / 1024 ** 3
    total_cubes = 24
    free_cubes = int(total_cubes * free / total)
    return f'VRAM: {total - free:.2f}/{total:.2f}GB\t VRAM:[' + (
            total_cubes - free_cubes) * '▮' + free_cubes * '▯' + ']'
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: i love that, it's the first one that updates correctly and it looks sick